# TypeError: *.getMonth is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to build a javascript function that will auto-fill 14 days of a calendar with dates leading up to the last date, which is picked by a datepicker. So far my code is:

```
function filldates() {

datepicked = document.getElementById("period-ending").value;
s = datepicked.split('/');
enddate = new Date(s[2], s[0], s[1]);
date1 = enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate()-14);
day1 = date1.getMonth() + 1;
month1 = date1.getDate();
var firstday = day1 + '/' + month1;
document.getElementById("date-1").value = firstday;
}
```

However the developer's console keeps telling me that date1.getMonth is not a function. I'm confused because all of the tutorials and examples I've been looking at are based around something like: "var today = new Date(); var month = today.getMonth() + 1;"

Is this an implementation problem?

Comment: You need to use `var` for **all** your local variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `setDate()` function mutates its context date. It does not return a new Date instance.

If you want to create a new date instance that's some number of days ahead of another one:

```
function daysAfter(d, days) {
  var nd = new Date(d.getTime());
  nd.setDate(d.getDate() + days);
  return nd;
}
```

Then if you've got a date, you can create a date 14 days after it like this:

```
var someDate = ... whatever ... ;
var fourteenDaysAfter = daysAfter(someDate, 14);
```

You can then use the `.getMonth()` and `.getDate()` accessors to do whatever formatting you want. Keep in mind that months are numbered from zero in JavaScript.

*edit* for dates *before* a date just pass a negative number.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your answer because I'm just not sure where I'm supposed to get the period ending date info. The user picks the last day of the pay period ("period-ending") using datepicker, which I'm converting to a date using "enddate = new Date(s[2], s[0], s[1]);" but your approach is completely different.

Comment: @JasonBoyce that function generates a date some number of days distant from a given date. If you want the date 14 days before that (which seems like an oversimplification for payroll, but whatever), you'd pass in the end date and `-14`, and the function returns a new date object representing 14 days before that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I just needed a couple of days to figure out where I was supposed to put the generated date to work on. Thanks for the help!